# Remove specific label/page just from URL in IBM Websphere Portal 8.5

Tags: url, websphere, websphere-8, friendly-url

I have created a label called "home" and inside that I have a page called "About-us", so the URL would be **http://hostname/home/About-us**.

I want to remove "home" from my URL(without removing "home" label from manage pages) to make it look like **http://hostname/About-us**.

Answer (score 0):

In the Manage Pages , there is an option to Move the page.

1. Go to **Manage Pages**
2. **Mark** the page which you would like to move
3. Go to the page where you would like to move this page.
4. Click on **Move**

[Detailed steps availalble here](https://icustomer.edelweisstokio.in/wps/iehs/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.wp.admin.help%2Fpanel_help%2Fh_mp_move_pages.html)